# Understanding x86 Assembly Code from C code

Tags: c, assembly

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", "hello");
    }
}
```

ASM:

```
    .file   "simple_loop.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hello"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp # push ebp onto stack
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp # setup base pointer or stack ?
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp # ? 
    subl    $32, %esp # ?
    movl    $0, 28(%esp) # i = 0
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp) # point stack pointer to "hello" ?
    call    puts # print "hello"
    addl    $1, 28(%esp) # i++
.L2:
    cmpl    $9, 28(%esp) # if i < 9
    jle .L3              # goto l3
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
```

So I am trying to improve my understanding of x86 assembly code.  For the above code, I marked off what I believe I understand.  As for the question marked content, could someone share some light?  Also, if any of my comments are off, please let me know.

Comment: My assembly knowledge is limited to MIPS rather than x86 so I can't really help with saying whether you are right so far or not. I can however give you the link to the book I plan on going through at some point to learn x86 assembly. It's all in a PDF here: [http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/aoa.pdf](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/aoa.pdf)

Comment: What are your doubts exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
andl    $-16, %esp # ? 
subl    $32, %esp # ?
```

This reserves some space on the stack. First, the `andl` instruction rounds the `%esp` register down to the next lowest multiple of 16 bytes (exercise: find out what the binary value of `-16` is to see why). Then, the `subl` instruction moves the stack pointer down a bit further (32 bytes), reserving some more space (which it will use next). I suspect this rounding is done so that access through the `%esp` register is slightly more efficient (but you'd have to inspect your processor data sheets to figure out why).

```
movl    $.LC0, (%esp) # point stack pointer to "hello" ?
```

This places the *address* of the string `"hello"` onto the stack (this instruction doesn't change the value of the `%esp` register itself). Apparently your compiler considers it more efficient to move data onto the stack directly, rather than to use the `push` instruction.